# Not able to use wget from ec2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, wget, amazon-vpc

I am trying to download some packages from ec2 instance. But it is not working. For example while I try to download elasticsearch it is pausing after this message

```
$wget https://download.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-1.4.0.tar.gz
--2017-11-24 07:51:29--  https://download.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-1.4.0.tar.gz
Resolving download.elastic.co (download.elastic.co)... 23.21.118.61, 54.225.188.6, 54.235.82.130, ...
Connecting to download.elastic.co (download.elastic.co)|23.21.118.61|:443..
```

But the same is working in my PC. I am able to ping from the ec2 instance.

```
$ping google.com
PING google.com (172.217.3.206) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from sea15s12-in-f14.1e100.net (172.217.3.206): icmp_seq=1 ttl=46 time=7.06 ms
64 bytes from sea15s12-in-f14.1e100.net (172.217.3.206): icmp_seq=2 ttl=46 time=7.10 ms
64 bytes from sea15s12-in-f14.1e100.net (172.217.3.206): icmp_seq=3 ttl=46 time=7.12 ms
```

And I am not using vpc in aws. This is a single ec2 instance I am deploying from a cloudformation template.

**EDIT : 1**

I used Elastic IP. When I dont use elastic IP I get the following error while installing nginx,

```
================================================================================
 Package              Arch        Version                  Repository      Size
================================================================================
Installing:
 nginx                x86_64      1:1.12.1-1.33.amzn1      amzn-main      561 k
Installing for dependencies:
 gperftools-libs      x86_64      2.0-11.5.amzn1           amzn-main      570 k
 libunwind            x86_64      1.1-10.8.amzn1           amzn-main       72 k

Transaction Summary
================================================================================
Install  1 Package (+2 Dependent packages)

Total download size: 1.2 M
Installed size: 2.9 M
Downloading packages:
http://packages.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/2017.09/main/154a6dd467e2/x86_64/Packages/gperftools-libs-2.0-11.5.amzn1.x86_64.rpm?instance_id=i-0d2c49307ac221d88&region=us-west-2: [Errno 12] Timeout on http://packages.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/2017.09/main/154a6dd467e2/x86_64/Packages/gperftools-libs-2.0-11.5.amzn1.x86_64.rpm?instance_id=i-0d2c49307ac221d88&region=us-west-2: (28, 'Connection timed out after 10001 milliseconds')
Trying other mirror.
http://packages.us-west-1.amazonaws.com/2017.09/main/154a6dd467e2/x86_64/Packages/gperftools-libs-2.0-11.5.amzn1.x86_64.rpm?instance_id=i-0d2c49307ac221d88&region=us-west-2: [Errno 12] Timeout on http://packages.us-west-1.amazonaws.com/2017.09/main/154a6dd467e2/x86_64/Packages/gperftools-libs-2.0-11.5.amzn1.x86_64.rpm?instance_id=i-0d2c49307ac221d88&region=us-west-2: (28, 'Connection timed out after 10001 milliseconds')
Trying other mirror.
```

Could someone help me with this issue?

Comment: Have you checked the security group attached to the instance to make sure that outbound http/https traffic is allowed?

Comment: @PicoutputCls - Yeah I opened 80 and 443 for inbound and `all traffic` for outbound.

Comment: You must be using VPC if you created your account after 2013-12-04. Anyway, could you also verify the ACL rules?

Comment: @sudo - . You were right. I think it has VPC. For the subnet ID associated with the instance, the ACL is set to `ALLOW` for both inbound and outbound

Comment: @Dany Can you perform a traceroute from the instance and see if you are getting return traffic. If internet connectivity to the domain is "OK", it might be that the EC2 IP has been blocked at the destination as mentioned in here:https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=101803
In this case, you might try stop/start the instance which will change the IP (unless you are using Elastic IP).

Comment: @sudo - It looks like traceroute info is masked in aws network(I am not 100% sure). I get `traceroute elastic.co
traceroute to elastic.co (52.33.146.13), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  * * *
 2  * * *` Also I use elastic IP. When I dont use elastic IP, terminate and start the instance, I get the above error while installing (Updated the question with `EDIT - 1`)

Comment: It sounds like you don't have Internet access without an EIP, which means you don't have a NAT device, or it isn't properly configured.  Note that DNS always works in VPC because of how it is implemented, so successful name resolution does not prove whether you have Internet access.

Comment: Did you attach InternetGateway to your VPC. Even if NAT / Security groups are properly configured, if you don't have IG, outbound traffic will not reach Internet @Dany